# Does $1^z$ = 2 have complex solutions?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, logarithms, exponential-function

Saw some people arguing about this and now I am curious, too.

The more I look the more arguing there is and I am not math savvy enough to pick out the truth.
At first I thought that there are infinitely many solutions but currently I am swaying towards there being no solution.

Comment: How do you define $1^z$?

Comment: Depends how you define $1^z$ - in most generality as a multiply valued function it is the set $e^{2k \pi iz}, k \in \mathbb Z$ and then obviously there are solutions to $1^z=w$ for any $w \ne 0$; on the other hand, one can pick a specific branch for a given $k$ ($k=0$ is called principal branch usually and then it depends as then we get solutions only for $k \ne 0$ so for all non-principal branches only

Comment: It has (infinite many) complex solutions !

Comment: Believing complex exponentiation is well defined is illusionary.

Comment: Using the usual branch of $\log$, $1^z := \exp(z \log(1)) = \exp(0) = 1$.